# Issue with selection sort and using a findMin method in C

Tags: c, sorting, selection-sort

so I'm having an issue with a selection sort that I made in C. When implemented in one function, I can get the selection sort to work. However, when I do what my assignment asks, and use a findMin function that returns the minimum index an array, it doesn't sort it completely. I've tried to debug it using print statements but I can't seem to figure out what is going wrong.

Here is the sorting method I am using with the findMin method:

```
void sortMin2(int A[]) {
    int outer;
    int minIndex;
    for(outer = 0; outer < 5; outer++) {
        minIndex = findMin(A, outer, 5);
        if(minIndex != outer) {
                swap(&A[minIndex], &A[outer]);
        }//end if
    } // end for
}

int findMin(int A[], int i, int j) {
    int k; // for loop
    int index = 0;
    for(k = (i + 1); k < (j+1); k++) {
        if(A[k] < A[index]) {
            index = k;
        } // end if
    } // end for
    return index;
} // end findMin

void swap(int *i, int *j) {
    int temp = *i;
    *i = *j;
    *j = temp;
} // end swap
```

And here is my output when I run it on an array of five values:

```
Array Before: 4, 10, 9, 1, 3, 
4, 10, 9, 1, 3, 
1, 10, 9, 4, 3, 
10, 1, 9, 4, 3, 
10, 1, 3, 4, 9, 
10, 1, 3, 9, 4, 
Array after: 4, 1, 3, 9, 10,
```

Now, here is my selection sort method that does work find (ie. properly sorts it).

```
void selectionSort2(int A[]) {
    int outer; // for loops
    int inner;
    int minimum = 0;
    //int minIndex = 0;
    for(outer = 0; outer < 5; outer++) {
        //minIndex = findMin(A, 0, 19);
        minimum = outer;
        for(inner = outer + 1; inner < 5; inner++) {
            if(A[minimum] > A[inner]) {
                minimum = inner;
            } // end if
        } // end inner for

        if(minimum != outer) {
            swap(&A[minimum], &A[outer]);
        } // end if
    } // end outer for
}
```

Does anyone see why my sortMin2 function doesn't actually sort it?

Comment: Given that you have a set of working code, you should compare the bad code to the good code line-by-line, and on each line ask yourself, "Do these two lines do exactly the same thing, and if not, why not?"

Comment: I've tried to trace it and figure out why it's not working / doing the same thing. But I really can't figure it out :( Maybe I've been looking at it too long

Comment: The first thing I would do is make all the variable names match. In the working code, you have variables `outer`, `inner`, and `minimum`. The `findMin` function should have exactly the same variables. The only oddball is the parameter called `j` which corresponds to the number `5` in the working code. You need to come up with a descriptive name for that parameter, like `arraySize`, or `size` or `length`.  But all the other parameters and variables can/should have the exact same name as in the working code. And then the code in `findMin` should be identical to the working code.

Comment: Why in `findMin(...)` method, the `for` loop has `k < (j+1)` as terminating condition. Don't you think, it should be `k < j`? Since `j + 1` will lead to `6`, hence the loop will go till `j = 5`, which will lead to undefined behaviour.

Comment: In my directions, it said that the user should input from A[i] to A[j], so if I did k < j, it would actually skip the last element at A[j].

Comment: Not sure how I didn't see that D: Thank you. The problem was not setting index to i.

Answer (score 0):

Some thingies, inside the code, are not in the right sense.

Why in `findMin(...)` method, the `for` loop has `k < (j+1)` as terminating condition. Don't you think, it should be `k < j`? Since `j + 1` will lead to `6`, hence the loop will go till `j = 5`, which will lead to undefined behaviour(as it is more than the bounds of the array A). Array indices start from `0`. Since the size is `5`, hence the indices are in the range of `0 - 4`.

Moreover, the value of `index` is never changing. It always starts from `0` in every iteration. Instead it should be `int index = i`, inside the `findMin(...)` function, as in `Selection Sort` we find the smallest element, and put it on the left hand side, to it's rightful position, hence next time, we start from a place, one ahead of this location.

And inside the `sortMin2(...)` function, you failed to call `swap(...)`, in case you have the new index to swap values with.

Here is the modified version, of the snippet:

```
int findMin(int A[], int i, int j) {
    int k; // for loop
    int index = i;
    for(k = (i + 1); k < (j); k++) {
        if(A[k] < A[index]) {
            index = k;
        } // end if
    } // end for
    return index;
} // end findMin

void swap(int *i, int *j) {
    int temp = *i;
    *i = *j;
    *j = temp;
} // e

void display(int A[])
{
    int i = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < 5; ++i)
        printf("%d\t", A[i]);
    printf("\n");
}

void sortMin2(int A[]) {
    int outer = 0;
    int minIndex = -1;
    for(outer = 0; outer < 5; outer++) {
        minIndex = findMin(A, outer, 5);
        if(minIndex != outer) {
            swap(&A[minIndex], &A[outer]);
            display(A);
        }//end if
    } // end for
}
```